# Operator "<<" overflow of doubly linked list. C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, doubly-linked-list, ostream

I'm having trouble creating the overload function of "<<" for my doubly linked list.

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef SORTEDLIST_H
#define SORTEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>

class SortedList {

private:
    typedef struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
    }*nodePtr;

    int theSize;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr tail;

public:
    SortedList();
    //~SortedList();
    void insertItem(int inData);
    bool deleteItem(int delData);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& ot, const SortedList& sL);
    int size() const;
    bool empty() const;



};



#endif
```

Here is my constructor:

```
SortedList::SortedList() {
    //Set pointers equal to NULL
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    theSize = 0;

    head = new node; //create new node of 3 parts: head, data and prev
    tail = new node; //create new node of 3 parts: head, data and prev
    head->next = tail; //next partition points to tail
    head->prev = NULL; //not necessary to put in?
    tail->prev = head; //prev partition points to head
    tail->next = NULL; //not necessary to put in?
    /*temp->next = tail; //access the node the temp pointer is pointing to, set the 'next' part equal to tail*/

}
```

and here is the ostream overload function I can't get to work:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ot, const SortedList& sL)
{
    sL.nodePtr temp;
    temp = sL.head->next;
    while (temp != sL.tail) {
        ot << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    ot << "\n";
}
```

It keeps telling me sL.NodePtr, sL.head, sL.tail are inaccessible. I do have it set as friend function so I am unsure why.

Comment: You don't return anything.

Comment: that and `return ot;`

Comment: mWebber in case you are coming in from Java or C#, C++ uses `::` not `.`, to resolve scopes, and scope cannot be resolved from a variable, you have to resolve it based on type. Most of the time you know the type and if you don't, [use `decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

Comment: I tried your code and got different errors than you (`'ostream' does not name a type`, and after that was fixed: `invalid use of 'SortedList::nodePtr'`). My conclusion is that you have not provided sufficient context; you did not provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your implementation of `operator<<`:

- `sL.nodePtr` needs to be `SortedList::nodePtr`.
- the `while` loop is all wrong.  It is not accounting for an empty list, and it ignores the `tail` node of a non-empty list.  Oh wait, your list makes use of **dummy** nodes for its `head` and `tail`, which is completely unnecessary and just complicates the class's design.  Get rid of the dummies altogether.
- it doesn't `return` anything.  It needs to return `ot`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
SortedList::SortedList() {
    //Set pointers equal to NULL
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    theSize = 0;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ot, const SortedList& sL)
{
    SortedList::nodePtr temp = sL.head;
    while (temp) {
        ot << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    ot << "\n";
    return ot;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ot, const SortedList& sL)
{
    for(SortedList::nodePtr temp = sL.head; temp; temp = temp->next) {
        ot << temp->data << " ";
    }
    ot << "\n";
    return ot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your operator overload doesn't return anything so it has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: Might want to come back and revisit this answer. While this is true, the asker didn't get far enough to encounter the logical errors in the code. They got stopped by a compiler error.

Comment: Thankyou. It turned out my header file and .cpp did not both contain "using namespace std" so the friend part wasn't working, as it saw operator<< and operator<< in the two files as different things.

Comment: However, despite adding namespace in, sL.temp isn't working while sL.head are. sL is highlighted as "not a modifiable L value."

Comment: @MWeber See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/). And there is no `temp` member in your `SortedList` class, so `sL.temp` doesn't exist.

Comment: That and `using namespace std` can be particularly harmful when placed in a header. Other people using your header may have written their code believing the contents of the `std` namespace have been safely walled off inside the `std` namespace, but as soon as they include your header, their code becomes infested with mystery errors. Once they figure it out, they drop by your cubicle and the conversation tends to get unpleasant.